# jQuery class is removed after mouse exits the link

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added a class called 'active' to the navigation menu that has class selected already. When I click on either the home menu item or the projects menu item, the class is added, but when I remove my mouse from the link on the menu, the class is removed. I am working with the Twitter Bootstrap framework, so I don't know if the behavior is because of my code or because of the Bootstrap code. How do I get the class to stay on the link as long as the other class "selected" exists? Thanks for any help.

jQuery

```
$('#nav_14623').addClass('nav');
$('#nav_14623').addClass('nav-pills');
$('#nav_14623 li.selected').addClass('active');
```

css related to it (as far as I know):

```
.nav-pills > li.active > a,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #428bca;
}
```

link to the website: http://jshub.designangler.com

Comment: This "active class" is native from the framework. Try to use another name for your class.

Comment: @MichaelVidal I am trying to add the active class to the navigation so that it will apply these styles. I am not creating my own css code for the active class or am I understanding your comment wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `Java_DynMenusSelectedCSS.js` on lines 49 - 52:

```
if (val)
    this.className = val + " selected";
else
    this.className = "selected";
```

The problem is, if your nav-pills have any *other* classes (such as "active"), once you mouseout, the className property is set to "selected," thus removing the extra classes.

This is an alternative for that code:

```
if (val)
    this.className = val + " " + this.className;
else
    this.className = this.className.replace(val, "");
```

I'm not sure where you got this code, but there is even a comment in there that mentions this issue.

Comment: It is Adobe Business Catalyst code. The site is built on their CMS. I did not write that specific code. Thank you for bringing it to my attention so I can develop with this in mind in the future. Thanks. =)

Comment: No problem. I just googled it and saw the same thing. That's too bad they introduced bugs into your code. :(

Comment: I just worked with their class by overwriting the bootstrap css for that class. It seemed to do the job. Thanks for the help.